# How Cursor, WHILE loop is working in DB2 i-Series

Tags: sql, db2, iseries-navigator

Just trying to understand how many times will "EXECUTE SQLStmt" run considering DISTINCT Col returns 5 rows while COUNT(*) returns 10 rows.

```
DECLARE c1 Cursor with return for 
SELECT Distinct Col as LIB FROM Page.Libraries 
ORDER BY Col;

SET numrecs = 0;
SET numcount = 1;
SET c_LIB = ' ';

SELECT COUNT(*) INTO numrecs FROM Page.Libraries;

OPEN c1;
WHILE numcount <= numrecs DO
    P2 : BEGIN
        FETCH c1 INTO c_LIB;
        SQLStmt = 'insert statement' || c_LIB
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQLStmt;
        SET numcount = numcount + 1;
    END P2;
END WHILE;
```

I am familiar with SQL Server but got confused with Db2 syntax.

Comment: I'm assuming that when you FETCH for the 6th time you will get an error, since the cursor will be empty.

Comment: @BillGregg: Does that mean, FETCH is going to throw an error or it will still itterate with the last value?

Comment: I would say this isn't how I would do it in SQL server.

Comment: FETCH will "throw an error" (set SQLSTATE/SQLCODE); but it will be ignored since you don't test for it. And since no new values will (can) be retrieved, it'll most likely use whatever was last retrieved.